# Filling array with sequence

Tags: python, arrays, list, sequence

I am having number N and i want to make amount of arrays .for example with N=2
I need

```
(0,0),(0.5,0),(0,0.5),(1,1) ,(1,0.5), (0.5,1)
```

for `N=3` its like

```
(0,0,0),(0.5,0,0)...(0.5,0.5,0)....(1,0.5,0.5)...(1,1,1)
```

which are contain all combinations of `0, 0.5, 1`.

I tried to use cycle for ,but didn't find the way to solve the problem with any N.I prefer python `numpy` or java if its real.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything to do with Java. Please remove the [Java] tag.

Comment: You should start with some idea, before starting to type the code.

Comment: Sorry,it was missclick,removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate all the combinations.

```
def f(n):
    return list(itertools.product((0, .5, 1), repeat=n))

print(f(2))
# [(0, 0), (0, 0.5), (0, 1), (0.5, 0), (0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0.5), (1, 1)]
```

Edit:

If you only want the combinations of adjacent elements, we can use the `pairwise` recipe from the `itertools` documentation.

```
from itertools import tee, chain, product

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def f(n):
    values = (0, .5, 1)
    return list(chain.from_iterable(product(x, repeat=n) for x in pairwise(values)))

print(f(n))
# [(0, 0), (0, 0.5), (0.5, 0), (0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 1), (1, 0.5), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: I thought of it, but OP's example is not having `(0, 1)` in it. OPs example seems to have the adjacent elements only

Comment: I will try to use other itertools things,they are giving for types of combinations.